# jQuery tabs don't work (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'd like to put tabs onto one page of my wordpress website.
I have it organised this way on my page:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">content tab 1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">content tab 2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">content tab 3</div>
</div>
```

and such a line of php code in header.php file, right before wp_head();

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
```

My tabs don't wan't to start being tabs, still I see a bulleted list instead of them.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the tabs (once the DOM is ready) in `header.php` like so.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Paste it just above the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` line and save the file and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I paste the code as you suggested, but nothing has changed on my page.

Maybe I should somehow connect jQuery scripts (downloaded from jquery.com) with my website or connect to the Google Libraries?